# How to resolve typescript TS7031 error on v-slot vuejes?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vee-validate

I'm using Vue.js 3 with Typescript and vee-validate and I have an error during building project.

**semantic error TS7031: Binding element 'field' implicitly has an 'any' type.**

This is because I use v-slot with vee validate values in the Field vee-validate component.

```
  <Field
    name="fieldDate"
    :label="libelle"
    :rules="`formatDateValide:${formatDate}|dateBetween:${formatDate},${dateMin},${dateMax}`"
    v-slot="{field, meta}"
  >
```

How can I define the types of this valuee or how can I deactivate this error ?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just add this conf to your tsconfig.json file :

```
"noImplicitAny": false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the type by adding it directly into the `v-slot` directive. For example:

```
<Field
    name="fieldDate"
    :label="libelle"
    v-slot="{field, meta}: {FieldType, MetaType}"
>
```